# How to not apply a GPO to only one user?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I have a group policy applied at the domain level for complex passwords. I have one user that I want to have a simple password. From my research, I went to the delegation tab of the specific GPO, and made a custom entry for the user account with the permissions "read - allow" and then "apply group policy - deny." I still cannot change their password to a simple password from the end user account or from Active Directory. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen, GPO delegation allows users permissions to see or manage the GPO, but does not apply the GPO to the OU or the User. What needs to happen is you need to get the GPO applied to the User or OU. There are two ways to do this:

**Easy Way (Best Practice)**

1. Create an OU in Active Directory and move the user into that OU
2. Either create a new GPO or link an existing GPO to that OU
3. After that is done run **gpupdate** on the users computer or wait the default time for the change to propagate.

**Another Way (Harder to Manage Changes)**

1. Open the GPO that you have created and go to the Scope tab
2. In the Security Filtering tab add the required user.
3. After that is done run **gpupdate** on the users computer or wait the default time for the change to propagate.

The reason why you should stay away from Security Filtering, is that it can cause major headaches for you in the future when troubleshooting GPOs. To make sure that the GPO is being applied to the user run the Resultant Set of Policy program ([RSoP Documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/312321/how-to-use-resultant-set-of-policy-logging-to-gather-computer-policy-i)).